# Super Smash Bros Ultimate on Switch - Black Screen after Title Screen

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Every time I start Smash Ultimate, the intro cutscene plays, and the title screen appears.

After I press a button, the screen goes black, and doesn’t do anything afterwards.

I tried restarting the game, restarting the Switch, powering off the Switch then turning it on again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turning on airplane mode solves the issue, as the black screen occurs when connecting to wifi that has a weak signal.

You can turn wifi back on after you've got the game going!

Solution pulled from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/a5kfd2/black_screen_after_title_screen/) and [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189706-nintendo-switch/77341847)

Comment: I can confirm that the black screen appears when the Switch is connected to WiFi, but has no access to the internet. When it happens, you can try waiting too, although it can take several minutes before the game gives up trying to access the internet.

Comment: You can't turn on airplane mode if the Switch is docked :-/